# Redirecting from local html page to online html page

Tags: html, redirect

I want to make a html-based document which I'm going to distribute through the Internet.

Under certain situations, people don't have the internet access, and I want to make it available even under off-line circumstances.  So, I'm planning to:

1. distribute an off-line version of the html-based document,  and
2. keep its up-to-date version on the http server

I want people to see the up-to-date version of the document if possible. So, **I want to redirect the readers of the off-line version to the up-to-date version if they have an access to the Internet.**

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

---

Note: We can check whether a reader of a web page have an access to the Internet using JavaScript, but we cannot use this trick from a local html page unless we explicitly disable the security features of browsers.  This trick is basically to check whether a reader *still* has an access to the Internet like they had when they loaded the web page.

Comment: Why not use built-in offline functionality?  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/offline

Comment: Brad, 

Thank you for your comment.  Maybe because I don't know much about web technology, I'm not sure which feature of html5 allows us to redirect readers to the online web page.  Could you please specify which functionality allows us to do what I want?

Comment: I'm suggesting you change your plan completely, not distribute the offline version, and use the existing offline functionality built into the browser instead.

Comment: I see.  I haven't considered it.  I will check it whether it works. Thank you!